# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.19.1

Tags: php, nginx

I have installed `nginx version: nginx/1.19.1`, `PHP 7.4.8 (fpm-fcgi)` and `PHP 7.4.8 (cli)`.

***My nginx server-Block-configuration:***

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    

    root /var/www/html;


    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name x.x.x.x;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

    }

    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

***I test http://x.x.x.x/info.php its give me error***

[image]

***Nginx-logs error:***

```
2020/07/30 10:30:10 [crit] 24996#24996: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 37.111.128.199, server: 54.175.13.25, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "54.175.13.25"
```

Gives me permission-denied error so
Why this happed?

Comment: Does the socket `/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` exist? Does Nginx have the permission to access it?

Comment: Yes socket exist

Answer (score 4):

Take alot of time to resolving

**I resolved by changing in the etc/nginx/nginx.conf {user nginx} to {user www-data} its actually permission issue then save and restart the nginx(sudo systemctl restart nginx).**

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: It's *really* take a lot of time to resolving. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so I am writing this as an answer.
What you did is one way.
The other way is to change the user in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
```

Personally, I would prefer changing the user for php-fpm rather than changing the user for nginx.

Cheers.